# set variable from input in format variable=value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need create script, which have variable as input and this variable is next use in script.
Format is

```
myscipt.sh variable1=value1 variable2=value2 .. variableN=valueN
```

I have created reading this value

```
myvar=$(echo $@ | tr " " "\n")
for x in $variable
do
  echo $x
done
```

and now i need value from x (variable1=value1) as variable with name variable1 which content value1.
Thank you for advice.

Comment: The argument syntax you propose is highly nonstandard -- the only standard unix program I can think of that uses this is `dd`, and it's syntax was copied from another OS (maybe as a joke). I recommend learning about more standard option and argument syntaxes, and using that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Isn't awk doing something similar too? I also vaguely remember that programs coming from the IBM world, often have this NAME=VALUE way of parameter passing, so if the OP is happy with it, why not. Of course it is more inconvenient to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inline variable declare **before** your script on same command line:

```
variable1=value1 variable2=value2 variableN=valueN bash myscipt.sh
```

Then inside `myscipt.sh` you can check values of these variables using:

```
declare -p variable1 variable2 variableN
```

Note that these variables will not be available in current shell after your script is done.

Comment: Your approach is a bit dangerous. Note that the OP wants to have a mechanism of "parameter naming", while in your approach, the variables become environment variables, i.e. automatically end up in the environments of all sub processes. This can have disastrous (i.e. hard to debug) effects if one chooses by chance a parameter name who also happens to be an important environment variable for some child process in the process hierarchy.